# Nested loops to create docx file from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, python-docx

I have a dataframe containing survey comments. There is one column with the group number for each respondent. Then there are several columns containing the question text in the header row and responses in the subsequent rows. Not everyone responded to every question so there are blank cells.

I want to use the docx package to output the comments to a Word file. I would like to show the question text as a heading, below that show the group number as a heading (grouping the responses by group number), below that show the question comments in a bulleted list, and then move to the next question and repeat. Also, I don't want to output the blank cells.

The code below gives an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
import docx
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import numpy as np
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION
from docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['Group 1', 'Comment A', 'Comment B', 'Comment C'], ['Group 2', 'Comment D', '', ''], ['Group 2', 'Comment E', '', 'Comment F'], ['Group 1', '', 'Comment G', 'Comment H'], ] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Group', 'Question 1', 'Question 2', 'Question 3']) 
print(df)

# create file
doc = Document()

sections = doc.sections
section = sections[0]

# Convert to landscape orientation
new_width, new_height = section.page_height, section.page_width
section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
section.page_width = new_width
section.page_height = new_height

# Document Title
doc.add_heading('Document Title', level=0)

# Opening text
doc.add_paragraph('Some text...')

# Do I need to sort by 'Group' before doing the loops?

# loop through the questions - this isn't working
for column in df[2:]:
    # create a heading for each question
    doc.add_heading(column, level=1)
    for g in df.Group:
        # create a heading for each question
        doc.add_heading(g, level=3)
        for c in df[g]:
            doc.add_paragraph(c, style='List Bullet')

# save the doc
doc.save('./test.docx')
```

Output would be:

```
Document Title

Some text...

Question 1

Group 1
 - Comment A

Group 2
 - Comment D
 - Comment E

Question 2

Group 1
 - Comment B
 - Comment G

Question 3

Group 1
 - Comment C
 - Comment H

Group 2
 - Comment F
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for the loop:

```
# loop through the questions
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    # create a heading for each question
    doc.add_heading(column, level=3)
    ###Make a new dataframe with only Group and column of interest
    new_df = df[['Group', column]]
    ###Make list of all units
    unit_list = list(new_df['Group'].unique())
    ###Make list of comments in each unit for this column
    for unit in unit_list:
        comments = [row[2] for row in new_df.itertuples() if row[1] == unit]
        comments = [i for i in comments if len(i) > 0]
        ###If there were any comments in this unit, add the unit as a subheader
        if len(comments) > 0:
            doc.add_heading(unit, level=4)
            # Bullet list of comments
            for c in comments:
                doc.add_paragraph(c, style='List Bullet')
```